# R: Get JSON into R Dataframe

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I'm trying to recompile old code that used to work. Running into some challenges. MWE below:

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
library("stringr")
library("jsonlite")
library("rgeos")
library("maptools")
library("stringr")
library("RJSONIO")

push <- readRDS("lq/lq_list.Rdata") # restore R object from a file
```

`push` looks like:

```
[898] "{title: \"La Quinta Inn Vancouver Airport\", innNumber: \"0759\", latitude:\n                        \"49.177832\", longitude: \"-123.127116\", imagePath: \"/bin/lq-com/hotelSearchImage.0759.jpg\", isInnAndSuites: \"false\", street: \"8640 Alexandra Rd\", street2: \"\", city: \"Richmond\", stateProv: \"BC\", postalCode: \"V6X 1C4\", countryDisplay: \"Canada\"\n            }"                                                                 
[899] "{title: \"La Quinta Inn & Suites Oshawa\", innNumber: \"6601\", latitude:\n                        \"43.898034\", longitude: \"-78.861257\", imagePath: \"/bin/lq-com/hotelSearchImage.6601.jpg\", isInnAndSuites: \"true\", street: \"63 King Street East\", street2: \"\", city: \"Oshawa\", stateProv: \"ON\", postalCode: \"L1H 1B4\", countryDisplay: \"Canada\"\n            }"
```

Rest of my code:

```
hotels <- data.frame(Title=character(), InnNumber=character(), Latitude=character(),Longitude= character(),
                 ImagePath=character(), isInnAndSuites= character(),   
                 street = character(), street2=character(), city = character(), stateProv=character(),
                 postalCode = character(), countryDisplay=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  # create empty data frame
  ## For-loop to parse the data for remaining La Quinta inns, 2:899 and store them in `tmp`.
for (i in 2:length(push)){
  json_file <- fromJSON(push[i])

  ## Added for robustness: replaces NULL entries for inn column cells with NAs. 
  ## Can be removed without problems.
  json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
    x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
  })
  tmp <- rbind(tmp,data.frame(do.call("cbind",json_file)))
}

hotels <- tmp[!duplicated(tmp$nnNumbe),]

## Fix header names screwed up by fromJSON()
colnames(hotels) <- c("Title","InnNumber","Latitude","Longitude", "ImagePath", "isInnAndSuites","street","street2", "city", "stateProv",
                "postalCode", "countryDisplay")
```

Error message:

```
 Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

This suggests that `tmp <- rbind(tmp,data.frame(do.call("cbind",json_file)))` has a problem. But I'm not sure why the number of columns differs if I'm already replacing NULLs with NAs.

Comment: A simple debug attempt would be to replace `rbind` with `dplyr::bind_rows` (which doesn't require the same columns) and look at the results.

Comment: @Gregor thanks, but i managed to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of my data manipulation prior to the for loop I had to convert my data from a character vector into a list by adding one line of code as shown below:

```
for (i in 2:length(push)){
   json_file <- fromJSON(push[i])
   json_file <- as.list(json_file)
   json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
     x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
   unlist(x)
   })
   tmp <- rbind(tmp,data.frame(do.call("cbind",json_file)))
 }
```